# Nested for-loop: giving concatenated result

Tags: c#

I am currently finding it hard to grasp the output from a simple nested for-loop

```
int result = 0;

for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
{
    for (int j = 1; j <= 2; j++)
    {
        result = result +i;
    }
}
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Which gives the output of **12**. I understand that the result for j is 1 and 2, but just cannot grasp why the final result is **12** instead of 3?

Can someone explain please?

Comment: Step through it in your debugger. Follow the logic step by step, line by line, iteration by iteration. Then you'll know.

Comment: 0+1+1+2+2+6+6=12. Think about what your loop does and add more outputs in between to show the current value of result..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your outer loop has three iterations. On each of those three iterations, you're running the inner loop:

```
for (int j = 1; j <= 2; j++)
{
    result = result +i;
}
```

Given that the body of the loop doesn't depend on `j`, and the inner loop will always run twice, we can replace the whole of the inner loop with:

```
result = result + i;
result = result + i;
```

Or to simplify it:

```
result = result + (i * 2);
```

So now the whole code is equivalent to:

```
int result = 0;

for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
{
    result = result + (i * 2);
}
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

So after the *first* iteration of the outer loop, `result` is 2 (we've added 2 to 0).

After the *second* iteration of the outer loop, `result` is 6 (we've added 4 to 2).

After the *third* iteration of the outer loop, `result` is 12 (we've added 6 to 6).

Comment: Thanks mate, what was I thinking just putting 1 and 2 together duh, Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

You are adding the value of `i` to `result` each iteration of the inner loop, and the inner loop runs 3 times (the 3 iterations of the outer loop). Therefore the first time the inner loop runs, you add `1` twice, the second time the inner loop runs you add `2` twice, and the final time it runs you add `3` twice:

```
result = 1 + 1 + 2 + 2 + 3 + 3 = 12
```

Answer (score 1):

run that test and you will see:

```
class Program
{
    public static void test()
    {
        int result = 0;

        for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("i["+i+"] : ");
            for (int j = 1; j <= 2; j++)
            {
                Console.Write(" when : j["+j+"]");
                Console.WriteLine("Adding " + i + "to" + result);
                result = result + i;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine(result);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        test();
    }
}
```